# Shrink the height of stack view on some view hidden

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

i have a problem with stack view. I have a vertical stack view with six button inside it.

Width of each button is the same as the stack view but the height of each button is 35. Depending upon the condition some of the buttons inside the stack view is hidden with

```
view.isHidden = true
```

But the buttons inside stack view fills the stack view height rather than shrinking the height of the stack view.

So what i want is keeping the button size same, i want to decrease the height of the stack view on some button hidden and expand it on some button display.

Comment: It should already do what you want unless you have some other constraint telling the stack view to be a certain height

Comment: @dan there is no any constraint for stack view but there is constraint for each button i.e. width equals: 250 and height: 35

Comment: There has to be _some_ constraint for the stack view. Constrain its top and sides, but _not_ its bottom or height, and now it will be free to grow or shrink vertically.

Comment: Like @matt said it should do this by default, and you can try that by checking and unchecking the hidden property in the Interface Builder, if you don't see the correct behavior in the Interface Builder then check your constraints again

Comment: @matt Thanks matt adding contraint to top and sides worked for me.

Comment: That's great, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be some constraint for the stack view if you want it to resize itself dynamically. Constrain its top and sides, but not its bottom or height, and now it will be free to grow or shrink vertically.